# Flex 3: Passing Array to Custom Component

Tags: apache-flex

I created a custom button component that accepts an array as a property.
I set the property as follows:

```
titleDims="[{Month: comboBox1.text, Year:comboBox2.text, Sales Order:comboBox3.text}]"
```

and I get the following error:

```
"1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon."
```

Wat is wrong with the array syntax?

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the array declaration?

Comment: I thought you had to do that when passing a parameter to an custom component

Comment: Is the custom component expecting a string or an array? isn't this json notation?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think Ivan wants to set a property in MXML, so quotes are required. Ivan, in the future, please specify if you're talking about ActionScript or MXML because it's not always easy to tell from context.

Comment: Yes. Good point. I was trying to do this in MXML not Actionscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cb1 = comboBox1; cb2 = comboBox2; cb3 = comboBox3;
```

Option A

```
titleDims="[{'Month': cb1.text, 'Year':cb2.text, 'Sales Order':cb3.text}]";
```

Option B

```
titleDims="[{Month: cb1.text, Year:cb2.text, SalesOrder:cb3.text}]";
```

Option C

```
titleDims="[{Month: cb1.text, Year:cb2.text, Sales_Order:cb3.text}]";
```

I'm ignoring your use of setting `titleDims` to a string first and assuming you have some code that needs it that way. In the future, you don't need to quote this declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is your formatting. Let's break it down:

```
titleDims = [{
    Month: comboBox1.text,
    Year:comboBox2.text,
    Sales Order:comboBox3.text // Whoops! There's a space here!
}]
```

I suggest to change it to `SalesOrder` instead.

If you *really* need spaces in the key, you can do this:

```
titleDims = [{
    'Month': comboBox1.text,
    'Year': comboBox2.text,
    'Sales Order': comboBox3.text
}]
```

Comment: +1 But interestingly, you can inject spaces in to variables names. Try this code: `var o:Object = {}; o["sales order"] = "something"; trace(o["sales order"]);` Now, as to why someone would do that, I don't know :)

Comment: I tried that and I get the same error. However, I will need spaces in the keys.

I even tried: titleDims="[{Month: comboBox1.text}]" and the same error is generated!

Comment: @OP Why the quotes? That makes it a string. Isn't `titleDims=[{Month:comboBox1.text}]` what you want?

Comment: just out of curiosity - `I will need spaces in the keys` - what kind of requirement is that?